# What is Meant by rel="nofollow noopener"?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, issue-tracking

When I make backlinks for [transfemme](https://www.transfemme.com/) we first see Target blank but now its showing  `rel="nofollow noopener"`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that, in theory, rel="noreferrer" should not have any SEO impact, while nofollow clearly specifies that the link does not endorse in any way the target URL.

nofollow was invented by Google back in 2005 in order to fight comment spam in blogs, any URL appearing in the comment section would not pass PR to the target webpage.

rel="noreferrer" mainly affects analytics, how did this visit landed to this page? where comes it from? noreferrer specifies to hide that kind of information.

I said **in theory** because there is currently no official documentation that explicitly indicates using noreferral would change anything in SEO terms, but it shouldn't.

Comment: you are explaining rel="noreferrer" but i ask for  rel="nofollow noopener" . is noreferrer and noopener is same ?

Comment: @NadirYaqoob - yes it's almost same concept that's why I explain to this